# How to find end coordinates?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I have `(x1, y1)` as start coordinates, length of the line from start coordinates and angle of the line with respect to x-axis.

I am working on an excel spreadsheet, to find the end coordinates `(x2,y2)`.

I am calculating the Distance using the formula `=SQRT((X2-X1)^2+(Y2-Y1)^2)`.

I am calculating the angle using the formula `=DEGREES(ATAN2((Y2-Y1),(X2-X1)))`

I manually entered start and end points on the excel sheet and plotted it in a  excel graph. I did this to compare if the formulae produces the same result as expected. The formulae I used are:

```
new_x = old_x + cos(Angle) * distance
new_y = old_y + sin(Angle) * distance
```

I am having trouble matching the end coordinates. Am I doing it the right way or am I missing something?

Any help would be really appreciated.

I have added the screenshot of my excel workings and chart for your references.

[Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/recNz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cos` and `sin` in Excel [take radians, not degrees](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-cos-function). So compute your angle using

`=ATAN2((Y2-Y1),(X2-X1)`

and it should work

Comment: Ha!! Wonderful. Thanks for the solution :) Worked like a charm.